# What is the exit strategy for Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I'm new to java concurrency so this may be a question already answered many time over or too obvious that I maybe missing something.

I am running as task like so:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(task)
```

My question is when its comes to end of executing the run method of task why does it not exit or why is the thread still alive? My understanding was once a threads `run()` completes the thread is no more and ceases to exist, right?

Answer (score 7):

`newSingleThreadExecutor` returns an `ExecutorService` which uses a single *thread* - it can still execute multiple *tasks*. It doesn't exit because you may want to supply more tasks.

You can use:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
service.execute(task);
service.shutdown();
```

to shut it down after the task has executed.

Answer (score 3):

the thread remains alive because its lifecycle is not tied to that of the tasks assigned to the executor; take a look at:

[javadoc for Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29)

you'll find that internally, the returned ExecutorService uses a single thread to sequentially run as many tasks as you assign to it, potentially instantiating a new thread if one of your tasks kills the original one.

Comment: I see the task is seperate from the thread life cycle. Thanks and will read up on the javadoc